# Can someone help me put in a setInterval() to create a traffic light sequence without using a button to change colours

Tags: javascript, html

This code allows the user to click a button to carry on the traffic light sequence:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>  

    <h1>JavaScript Task 3- Traffic Light Sequence </h1> 

  <img id="light" src="./assets/red.png" height="205" width="95">
  <button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>  
  <script> 
    var colours = ["./assets/red.png","./assets/red_and_amber.png", "./assets/green.png","./assets/amber.png" ];
    var index = 0;
    function changeLights() {
      index = index + 1;      
      if (index == colours.length) 
        index = 0;      
      var image = document.getElementById('light');     
      image.src = colours[index]; 
    } 
  </script>  
</body> 
</html>
```

I need to remove this button so that the different traffic light colours change continuously for a set amount of time. I know to use `setInteval()` but I am not sure where this needs to be in the code. For example, if a red light is showing, after 3000 milliseconds (for example) the red and amber light should show.

Answer (score 0):

To use `setInterval`, you just need:

```
setInterval(function() {
    //Do something every n milliseconds
}, n);//the number of milliseconds
```

As you are simply calling one function, it could be:

```
setInterval(changeLights, 3000);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var colours = ["red", "green", "yellow"];
var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == colours.length)
        index = 0;
    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.style.backgroundColor = colours[index];
};

setInterval(function() {
    changeLights()
}, 3000);

changeLights();
```

```css
#light{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Task 3- Traffic Light Sequence </h2>
<div id="light"></div>
```

You can achieve the same effect with `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`, if you put `setTimeout()` inside `changeLights` calling the very function `changeLights`:

```
setInterval(changeLights, 3000);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var colours = ["red", "green", "yellow"];
var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == colours.length)
        index = 0;
    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.style.backgroundColor = colours[index];
    setTimeout(changeLights, 3000);
};

changeLights();
```

```css
#light{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Task 3- Traffic Light Sequence </h2>
<div id="light"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put window.setInterval(changeLights, 3000); at the end of your code... Should work :)

-Mathew

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it.

Comment: If you like my answer please give it a upvote and tick it as correct Answer.